# How can I remove the ONEDRIVE Folder from Explorer?

Tags: onedrive

I have tried to do this here: [remove_ONEDRIVE_from_Explorer](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/remove-onedrive-from-file-explorer.html#:%7E:text=Open%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Apps%20%26,button%20beside%20the%20OneDrive%20app.&text=Tip%3A%20Even%20if%20you%20delete,remain%20in%20your%20File%20Explorer.) but on my Win 11 System there is no such a KEY in the registry: `018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6`
Does one here know how I can remove the Ondrive Folders after deinstall onedrive app?
thanks
Walter